# how to use IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY IN grails 3 spring-security

Tags: grails, spring-security

i'm setting up a new project in grails 3 with spring-security and want to authenticate controller using IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY.

i've already tried adding url to requestmap according to official documents

`@Secured(['IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'])`

i expect the output to redirect to login controller if not login

Comment: So you've added the annotation above to your controller yes? What happens now when you navigate to an action in this controller?

Answer (score 0):

I do this under the application.yml file grails-app/conf directory

grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap

https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#configGroovyMap

```
grails:
   plugin:
      springsecurity:
         interceptUrlMap:
            - pattern: '/**' #This can be any URL you want to customize
               access:
                  - 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'
```

Do not copy paste that. Yaml is very picky with whitespace. Use tabs.